# Adding GraphicDesign.SE to suggestions list when flagging a post as off-topic

Tags: feature-request, migration

Today, the only site suggested as an alternative when flagging a post as off-topic is Meta UX. However, a very large share of off-topic questions should really go to graphic design (a distant second is SO for implementation questions).

On some other SE sites the frequent migration destinations are suggested inside the flagging wizard. This is from SO:

[image]

Should we add GD as an alternative destination to ours?

Comment: I brought this up (and SO) in http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/593/vote-to-close-options-should-include-gd-se-and-so but we were in Beta then. However since Graphic Design is a Beta I don't know if they'll add it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highly support this, and would also support a recommended migration destination for StackOverflow, since we do get a number of "how do I do X?" questions that are more relevant to a programmer audience.