# More options for migration in close requests

Tags: feature-request

OK, so I go to request a Q be closed, reason being it would be better answered elsewhere.

This option...

> [image]

... leads to these options ...

> [image]

Yeah, just the one site.

I suggest the following be added:

- [graphicdesign.stackexchange.com](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com)
- [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com)
- [english.stackexchange.com](http://english.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Ah, if only we could add quora.com onto the list, to get rid of the speculative/opinon/discussion questions.

Comment: Another possible site for consideration is [webapps.stackexchange.com](http://webapps.stackexchange.com). We've definitely gotten a few questions asking about how to use various web apps.

Answer (score 2):

Graphic design, yes, I'd agree with that being added there. Especially as we're now going to be migrating some of the better Icon Suggestion type questions over there.

English.se I don't really see a need for. We've only migrated two questions in the last 2 years to english ([this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/108177/symmetric-term-for-engaging-with-someone-over-sms-or-email) and [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114609/finish-complete-submit-or-finished-at-the-end-of-a-short-drag-and-drop-word-b)) so that's not really something that is probably necessary. (And if a question is posted here that really does belong there then it can still be flagged for mod attention and recommended for migration that way).

As for the suggestion of adding Stack Overflow to the list; no, I really don't like that idea. We get *far* too many flags and comments on questions from people saying 'this belongs on SO' when it quite blatantly does not and would be closed/deleted in no time should it hit that site.  That's a bad experience for those users, not to mention it annoys the SO community (and mods) no end! Again, if a question really *does* belong over there then us Mods can deal with that - such as speaking with the mods of SO to confirm. It's very rare that someone posts something here that is genuinely suited better to Stack Overflow. The opposite is far more common (something posted there that belongs here).

So I partially agree with you. Lets add GraphicDesign into the list, but not the other two as there's not really much call to do so.

It's not something us mods can add in directly though, we can get one of the Stack Exchange community managers to do it, provided we have a good case for doing it - which is what this post should prove. If we get a few more upvotes and no disagreements then I'll request we get GD added to the list.

Comment: Good point on SO. Any alternative suggestion for "implementation" questions?

Comment: graphicdesign.se would be not just for icon suggestions, but gd questions generally. Like this one: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/50512/good-english-british-sans-serif-fonts

Comment: Only two for english so far, but is that because it's not obvious how? english.se might be more suitable for [this](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/22997/english-version-or-english), [this](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/42261/english-gender-neutral-strings-for-named-people-in-programs), and possibly many more from [tag:copywriting].

Comment: Definitely on board for Graphic Design, agreed with the concerns about English/SO. Don't think there's enough need for English now, SO is too easy to miss-migrate (and it's a heck of a sharktank to throw the wrong question into). Even GD isn't *that* common of a target in terms of question count, but it's definitely relevant and overwhelmingly the most common target percent wise.

Comment: I agree with @Erics that the reason so few questions have been migrated to English.SE may be that English.SE isn't a listed option.

Answer (score 1):

We've been talking about this for ages ([2011](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/593/vote-to-close-options-should-include-gd-se-and-so), [2012](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1057/adding-graphicdesign-se-to-suggestions-list-when-flagging-a-post-as-off-topic)), specifically about GD.

I think that the conclusion regarding it was that it was a Beta site, so they couldn't/wouldn't "elevate" it to a full site status by including it in the official migration list. It's still in Beta, but maybe they'll reconsider. I'd be happy if this was done.