# Add Graphic Design to Migration list

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, migration

We've brought this up [multiple](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1057/adding-graphicdesign-se-to-suggestions-list-when-flagging-a-post-as-off-topic) [times](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1525/more-options-for-migration-in-close-requests) [in the past](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/593/vote-to-close-options-should-include-gd-se-and-so) and arrived at the conclusion that Graphic Design wasn't being added to the migration suggestions list because it was in Beta.

Well, [they've just graduated](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/870/new-design-launched?cb=1) (congrats!).

Now can we add it to the migration list please? :)

Answer (score 2):

Logically? The migration path makes sense. Graphic Design and User Experience are pretty easy to intertwine. The scopes are pretty adjacent.

However, we pick our migration paths based on usage statistics. In the last 90 days, there've been 23 migrations from this site to Graphic Design, of which 21% were rejected. The all-time count for migration is 68 posts over to Graphic Design, with a total rejection rate of about 12% (8 rejections, of which 4 were the 21% mentioned earlier).

So on the one hand, the frequency of migrations has picked up, being over half the previous lifetime of the site's migration rate. On the other hand, your rejection rate increased in line, being equal to the rate for the previous lifetime. And the overall numbers are still kind of low. Higher than some places, but still overall it's low. I'm not finding the numbers high enough to think that flagging for moderator attention would be insufficient or inefficient.

I'll be keeping an eye over the next 90 day cycle to see how the situation paints over that, but for now, the decision here is to not establish this path.

Comment: Awesome that the data shows that our gut feeling is wrong :)

Comment: Cool. One way in which this data may not be enough to describe the situation is the closing of questions which could be migrated. A good example is the closing of questions asking for icon suggestions as "off topic". It's been agreed that they are off topic on this site, but [GD is full of them](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=icon+suggestion), and they aren't usually suggested for migration. I believe they should be added to the stats. There may be other questions like these, but they're harder to put in a single category and to locate :).

Answer (score 1):

I say do it! Graphic Design has always been an obvious choice for migration.